# How to reinstall accidentally deleted calendar?

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, calendar

I accidentally removed the inbuilt calendar application. How can I get it back? I can't find it in the Ubuntu Software store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the gnome calendar, you can either install it using `apt-get` or `snap`:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-calendar
```

or

```
sudo snap install gnome-calendar
```

I prefer not to install using `snap`, since I found that those are slower to start.

Comment: It worked. Thanks.